# Combining VS Code intellisense extension with VS Code Debug Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've created a VS Code intelli-sense extension https://github.com/rt320/vscode-dfdl for Data Format Description Language (dfdl) https://daffodil.apache.org/docs/dfdl/.  Another team I am working with has created a daffodil (https://daffodil.apache.org/) debugger for VS Code the front end is TypeScript the backend is Scala. (daffodil is written in Scala).  The debugger is currently using a previously developed snippets file for dfdl intellisense.  The VS Code intellisense extension is based on the VS Code example https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/completions-sample. The stakeholders would like a single VS Code extension that provides the functionality in the debugger along with the intellisense functionality in a single extension. I am having trouble trying to combine the two separate extensions.  I would be interested if anyone has an suggestions or could point me to some code I could look at for ideas.

### Heading ##Update with more info:

Some time ago I created a snippets json file with intellisense entries for the dfdl language. The snippet file was incorporated into a separate debugger extension through the package.json file with an entry in the contributes section. Recently I created a TypeScript version of the intellisense that offers more functionality. I have been trying to combine the extension.ts file for the intellisense with the code for the debugger extension, but haven't been able to get it working. I'm looking for an example of how that might be done.

```
    [
       { 
          "language": "xml",
          "path": "./snippets/dfdl.json"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some time ago I created a snippets json file with intellisense entries for the dfdl language.  The snippet file was incorporated into a separate debugger extension through the package.json file with an entry in the contributes section.
    "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "xml",
        "path": "./snippets/dfdl.json"
      }
    ]

Comment: Recently I created a TypeScript version of the intellisense that offers more functionality. I have been trying to combine the extension.ts file for the intellisense with the code for the  debugger extension, but haven't been able to get it working.  I'm looking for an example of how that might be done.